# IONIC2 Building a custom audio streaming app with firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I was thinking of making an app which plays a specific set of small audio files stored away in a firebase database, or any other database on the cloud.
The number of files may exceed hundreds, so wrapping all the files in the app might not be the best of ideas.

I'd really like to know how to go about this problem.

Downloading only the required file from firebase when it's clicked and playing as its being downloaded all the while caching it for future playback seems plausible, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.
I'd appreciate a few pointers towards this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are thinking in the right direction.

You might use these things.

1. **App UI** - Ionic2 will provide you a very nice and easy to implement platform to create a UI. Please refer [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/) documentation for the basics and details about using Ionic2.
2. **Local Storage** - You can use this to store downloaded files. In any app where data is relatively large, using local storage is the smart choice. This helps you reducing the size of the initial app to be installed and download the content as and when needed.
3. **A well defined database** - Now, whether to use **non-structured (No-SQL)** or **structured (SQL)** is the first choice you have to make.

If it's just content - audio files download and play with no complex cross querying the database, then you can choose to use **non-structured (No-SQL) database** like Firebase database.

But, if you have good requirements for structuring data, query it with constraints like "Give me all the audio files list where a particular user has played it in last 10 days" or "Give me all the users who has played/downloaded a particular audio file more than 10 times" and so on, then you better use **structured (SQL) database** like PostgreSQL.

4. **RxJS** - Now, this might not be very important to do, but, if you use this from the start, it's a good choice. Advantages are, e.g. you might not have to wait for all the file to get downloaded before playing it. Use **Observables** and **Promises** for such a mechanism.

Could help with the specifics when needed. Hope this helps. :)